# Reading type <T> from config

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

I have a method with the below signature

```
public string Register<T>()
{
  //code
}
```

which can be invoked like this

`var result = Register<Employee>()`;

my requirement is to invoke the method by reading the type T from config file,

*ie:*
While invoking, instead of hardcoding "Employee", i should be able to supply it dynamically by reading the config file.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Is this by any chance for DI container registration? Most DI containers have config-file functionality built in.

Comment: @default.kramer: yes you got me, i'm using simpleinjector where there is no xml based configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use reflection, specifically [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx), but if you don't have the type at compile time it seems better to change the method signature to `Register(Type type)`. Then you can read the type out of the config file and pass it in directly.

**Edit**

If you add a reference to `SimpleInjector.Extensions`, you will be able to access non-generic registration methods. See [NonGenericRegistrationsExtensions.cs](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94569#1810697) in the source here. This will allow you to do something like this:

```
string typeName = GetTypeNameFromConfigFile();
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
container.RegisterSingle(type, type); // register as self
```

Then you don't need generics at all.

You might also want to read over [Advanced Scenarios](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios)

Comment: kramer : It worked, Thanks for your detailed analysis, you saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Type parameters are needed at compile time, so in order to do this, you'd need to make use of reflection.

[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 0):

On web.config

```
<appSettings>
<!-- The assembly name of the default type. Use the format Fully.Qualified.Class.Name, Assembly.FileName -->
<add key="DefaultType" value="MyTestApp.BusinessEntitites.Employee, MyTestApp.BusinessEntitites " />
</appSettings>
```

On C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type obj = Type.GetType(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultType"]);
    ConstructorInfo constructor = obj.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
    var myinstance = constructor.Invoke(null);
    var result = Register<myinstance>();
}
```

Comment: getting Error "The type or namespace name 'obj' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".., 
But i'm looking  for a solution like this..

Comment: @BrazilNut I edited my answer. Check the web.config section

Comment: This still won't compile because `obj` is an instance of `Type`, not a compile-time type parameter. Check dwerner's answer for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BrazilNut can you try this? Updated code.

Comment: @Nathan : still it wouldn't work for the above reason "default.kramer" mentioned

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956094/use-a-string-from-a-config-file-to-initilize-a-generic-type?rq=1